# Best list merging and manipulation technique

Tags: kotlin

So, I got a (mutable) list of `<TOKENS, Strings>` pairs that look something like this

```
...
Pair(IDENTIFIER, "A"),
Pair(TICKTICK, "``"),
Pair(IDENTIFIER, "_B")
...
```

I’d need to loop through the list and end merge to this:

```
...
Pair(IDENTIFER, "A_B")
...
```

So, basically find all `TICKTICK` token occurrences and merge the previous two tokens (i.e., create a new pair with the Strings added together).

My current idea was to do a `for` look looking for `TICKTICK` tokens and then remove previous, current and next and then insert a newly merged token.

It seems like there should be a more natural way…. *Any ideas?*

It also seems that I don’t have access to `iterator().previous` even though indicated by [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list-iterator/index.html)

Comment: In some ways, this is equivalent to a string's `replace` method that replaces substrings.

Comment: Yes. It's just that I need to keep track of the resulting token type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Kotlin 1.2, you can also use the new `windowed` stdlib function that represents the elements as snapshots of a sliding window, e.g.

```
println(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).windowed(3))
// [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Then check the pattern `IDENTIFIER, TICKTICK, IDENTIFIER` against the window and if it matches (and if the three items are not yet replaced) then store the information that you replace the items at these indices with a single one.

```
val pattern = listOf(IDENTIFIER, TICKTICK, IDENTIFIER)

// Stores indices of items that are not replaced:
val indicesOfNormalItems = items.indices.toMutableSet()
```

The loop over windows that also collects the resulting items into a map with the key of the first index of the triple:

```
val replaced = items.withIndex().windowed(pattern.size) { window ->
    val kinds = window.map { (_, item) -> item.first }
    if (kinds == pattern) {
        val windowFirstIndex = window.first().index
        if (windowFirstIndex in indicesOfNormalItems) {
            indicesOfNormalItems.removeAll(window.map { it.index })
            val (first, _, third) = window.map { it.value.second }
            return@windowed windowFirstIndex to (IDENTIFIER to first + third)
        }
    }
    null
}.filterNotNull().toMap()
```

Then collect the result, combining it from the items that were not replaced and the values from the map:

```
val result = items.indices.mapNotNull { index ->
    if (index in indicesOfNormalItems)
        items[index] else
        replaced[index]
}
```

Here's a complete runnable demo: [(link)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/a6bh6f3vbcvirk3cvip1kti4n6/mvrchhqjgj71f6csrkj94gpuq)

In Kotlin 1.1.x there's no `windowed` function, so you will have to implement it on your own or do the same with your code.

Comment: Nice! _but_ why is the "good stuff" always one major release away? I'm still in 1.1.3 :-(. Gives me some ideas for a different approach than my naive `for ` loop.

Comment: @RobertEkendahl, here's a [gist with my implementation of `windowed`](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/9e620eb0cd1e93fdb11e75f921897163) if it helps.

Comment: _Wow_ You're Kotlin-Fu is mighty. Will try to use that and your example above as see what happens